# SSD stopped working suddenly. Any chance of data recovery?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hard-drive-recovery, hard-drive-failure, disk-controller

I have been using a `Corsair Force 3 (120GB) SSD` since last 1.5 years.
Yesterday, the laptop freezed suddenly and I had to hard reset it.
Then it refused to boot as if no HDD was installed. This has happened earlier a couple of times. Usually, after a restart it used to work like normal but yesterday even after a few restarts the BIOS won't detect the HDD. I connected it to a different computer using USB to SATA converter and it still won't get detected.

From what it seems, the controller has gone kaput but there are chances that the data is still intact. I just need to confirm if what I am thinking is right. 
Also, is there any way I can purchase an exactly similar SSD and swap the controller / memory chips ? I know this would require some BGA level soldering but I can give that a try.

Comment: You are correct in your assumption, the controller (or just the physical SATA interface) is failing.  Or maybe it got a power surge and fried itself silly.  But I do wish you luck in this endeavor

Comment: Have you been keeping the firmware up-to-date?  Many data-recovery firms exists, but they are costly.  If you have not updated the firmware there is a slight chance it might work. If you can get a computer to recognize it enough to preform the update do that first.  Otherwise a data recovery company, or you can solder it at your own risk.

Comment: I haven't performed a firmware update. I tried updating the firmware but for the tool to make an update, the SSD should be detected and shown up in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SSDs its highly unlikely that you'd be able to get and data back unless it decides to be recognised again. I would try hot plugging it to a Linux computer watching the output of syslog (or wherever kernel measages go to on your machine)

Replacing the controller will not work, as it contains memory of how the data is mapped onto the NAND flash.

As a last resort I'd recommend putting the drive in cold and dry environment for a little bit. As weird as it sounds electronics work better at lower temperatures. take care to minimise condensation however.

When you do connect it back up, start copying data as fast as possible, with dd preferably.

If the data is truely important, you should consider data recovery company

Comment: Thanks for your answer Yarek T. I'd try hot plugging it to a Linux machine and watch for dmesg maybe. How do I put the drive in cold and dry environment ? How much cold should it be ? Should I put it inside a bag in a refrigerator ? Will that help ?

Comment: Sealed bag, wrapped in a paper tissue should do it. After maybe an hour take it out, Leave it for about 2 minutes, and plug it in. Be ready to initiate `dd` copy if it gets recognised. You'd need as much space as the disk is in size. Make sure everything is dry before you plug anything in. Water can damage your working computer =/. Good luck

Comment: Will try that and let you know ! Thanks a ton!!