# What happened with my ssd? Windows recognizing it with a weird name

Tags: windows, drivers, ssd

My `ssd` stops working.

This is the story, I was playing `Age Of Empires II` on `Steam`, then the game crashed, at that moment I could move the`mouse` but I could not close any applications, apparently `Explorer.exe` stopped working.

So I had to *turn off* the computer by pressing the **power button**, after that `windows 10` did not start again, I installed my old`hdd` (Runing`windows 7`) with the 2 disks (`Hdd` &`ssd`) and I did not see the`ssd` partition.

Connect the `ssd` to another computer (laptop) with an external box and this happens:

[image]

[image]

I just contact zotac for a RMA and now I'm watting for the solution.  But while this happen, Is there anything I could do?

Comment: The drive is corrupted/dead; what is it you want to "Do" while waiting for the replacement?

Comment: I was thiking of trying a repair software... :-S   Any idea?

Comment: The recommendation I always try to give people with dead drives, is try to run a live CD of linux (any flavor) to see if it can detect the drive. Sometimes linux can see drives that Windows can not. Obviously if you do see the drive in linux, back it up immediately

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/710394/ssd-stopped-working-suddenly-any-chance-of-data-recovery

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/506410/how-can-i-recover-dead-ssd-drives

Comment: I tryed with a linux live cd, but never starts with the ssd conected, if disconected linux starts