# M.2 SATA SSD not recognized by anything - any chance of data recovery?

Tags: ssd, data-recovery, hardware-failure, sata, m.2

A couple days ago my mom's laptop's SSD became unbootable. I thought maybe this was just a corruption of the boot partition, but when I checked the BIOS the disk wasn't listed anywhere. I tried reseating it, and still no luck. I've also tried it in another computer, same issue.

Today I got an M.2-to-USB device, which works for both NVMe and SATA, and is able to successfully read other disks of both types. However when I plug in this one, it's as if I didn't insert the disk at all. The device shows up on /dev/sdb, but a hexdump outputs literally NOTHING.

There are some absolutely critical files on that disk and I need to recover them. There's no visible physical damage to the disk, and it doesn't get excessively warm or anything. It's been kept inside the laptop up until this point, so I don't see how static damage would have occurred.

It's a SK Hynix HFS256G39TNH-73A0A/SC401M280S (The M/N scheme is very confusing).

And yes, I know, the data should have been backed up, and I'm going to set up backups to my instance of NextCloud. But for now, I need this data. Any idea what went wrong? Is there a software tool that can recover the data (and not send it anywhere)? How much would a DR company cost?

Comment: Any software would at a minimum require the device to be detected in bios

Comment: You're just going to have to price up some data recovery companies. Don't mess with it any further to give them the best shot at recovery.

Answer (score 0):

So get this, I found the answer here (https://superuser.com/a/710807/1296284) and tried it this morning, and sure enough it actually works. Whatever kind of witchcraft this is, I am very appreciative of it!

Comment: This is what you meant from the other answer I guess: "As a last resort I'd recommend putting the drive in cold and dry environment for a little bit. As weird as it sounds electronics work better at lower temperatures. take care to minimise condensation however."